# CSS print page-break-after not working with CSS Grid layout

Tags: css, page-break, css-grid

I'm using the new CSS3 layout technique defined by gridbyexample.com.
It's works very well except when I try to print the layout. Chrome and Firefox seem to be ignoring any page breaks and the landscape view mode I have defined in the CSS. I have a code pen for my project but it seems to change how it looks in print preview mode so it's only good for looking at HTML and CSS but not how the print will look. 
https://codepen.io/JeffreySpring/pen/rzjeKm

I have created a .zip file with all the files and images that can be downloaded from https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B0LdH-fKpAKeY0NRa290M25uTGc

Here is the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Steam Controller Bindings Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
</head>


<body cz-shortcut-listen="true" style="">

<ul class="wrapper">

    <li class="device">
        <div id="steamDeviceContainer">
            <div><h1>Couch Gamer's Witcher 3 Bindings</h1></div>
            <img src="img/steam_controller.png" alt="Steam Controller">
        </div>
        <div class="mappingGyroShift1">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader gyroShift1">Gyro<span class="boundTo gyroShift1">(Mouse Joystick)</span></h3>
            <div class="actionBind gyroShift1">Precision Crossbow/Bomb Aim</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Left Trigger</h3>
            <div class="actionBind">Use Witcher Senses</div>
            <div class="actionBind">Block or Counterattack</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Left Bumper</h3>
            <div class="actionBind">Quick choice menu</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Select Button</h3>
            <div class="actionBind">Pause Game/Game Options</div>
            <div class="actionBind">HOLD: Inventory Screen</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Left Grip</h3>
            <div class="actionBind">Use Item</div>
            <div class="actionBind gyroShift1">HOLD: (GYRO ON) Aim Crossbow/Bomb</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Right Trigger</h3>
            <div class="actionBind">Use Sign</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Right Bumper</h3>
            <div class="actionBind">Quick Save</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Start Button</h3>
            <div class="actionBind">In Game Menu</div>
            <div class="actionBind">HOLD: Map</div>
        </div>
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Right Grip</h3>
            <div class="actionBind modeShift1">Mode Shift Left TouchPad</div>
            <div class="actionBind modeShift1">Mode Shift A Button</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wide">
        <div class="mapping pageBreakAfter">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Left Joystick<span class="boundTo">(Joystick Move)</span></h3>
            <div class="actionBind">ROTATE: Move Character</div>
            <div class="actionBind">DOUBLE PRESS: Call your mount</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wide">
        <div class="mapping pageBreakAfter">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Face Buttons<span class="boundTo">(Button Pad)</span></h3>
            <div class="actionBind aBtn">A BUTTON: Interact/Roll</div>
            <div class="actionBind aBtn">A BUTTON HOLD: Run/Quick Swim/Gallop/Accelerate Boat</div>
            <div class="actionBind aBtn">A BUTTON QUICK DOUBLE PRESS THEN HOLD: Full Gallop</div>
            <div class="actionBind bBtn">B BUTTON: Jump/Dodge/Let helm go</div>
            <div class="actionBind bBtn">B BUTTON HOLD: Resurfacing</div>
            <div class="actionBind yBtn">Y BUTTON: Strong attack</div>
            <div class="actionBind xBtn">X BUTTON: Fast Attack</div>
            <div class="actionBind xBtn">X BUTTON HOLD: Submerging/Stop the Boat</div>
            <div class="actionBind modeShift1">A BUTTON: Autoloot</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wide">
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Left TouchPad<span class="boundTo">(4 way D-Pad)</span></h3>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD UP: Consumable 1/3</div>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD UP HOLD: Switch to Consumable 1/3</div>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD DOWN: Consumable 2/4</div>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD UP HOLD: Switch to Consumable 2/4</div>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD LEFT: Drawing or hiding steel sword</div>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD LEFT: Drawing or hiding silver sword</div>
            <div class="actionBind modeShift1">MODE SHIFT RIGHT GRIP: Radial Menu 1</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="wide">
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Right TouchPad<span class="boundTo">(4 way D-Pad)</span></h3>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD UP: Consumable 1/3</div>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD UP HOLD: Switch to Consumable 1/3</div>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD DOWN: Consumable 2/4</div>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD UP HOLD: Switch to Consumable 2/4</div>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD LEFT: Drawing or hiding steel sword</div>
            <div class="actionBind">D-PAD LEFT: Drawing or hiding silver sword</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="full">
        <div class="mappingModeShift1">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader modeShift1">Radial Menu 1<span
                    class="boundTo modeShift1">(6 button touch menu)</span></h3>
            <div class="actionBind modeShift1">BUTTON 1: Aard</div>
            <div class="actionBind modeShift1">BUTTON 2: Yrden</div>
            <div class="actionBind modeShift1">BUTTON 3: Igni</div>
            <div class="actionBind modeShift1">BUTTON 4: Quen</div>
            <div class="actionBind modeShift1">BUTTON 5: Axii</div>
            <div class="actionBind modeShift1">BUTTON 6: Swap Crossbow/Bomb</div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="full">
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Details</h3>
            <div class="notes">
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis efficitur arcu ut sapien ullamcorper,
                    vel ornare tellus venenatis. Pellentesque non sapien magna. Suspendisse potenti. Duis et turpis
                    sapien.
                    Donec turpis odio, posuere dignissim ornare semper, commodo a nunc. Nunc lacinia felis id elementum
                    vehicula.
                    Curabitur vel risus luctus, ornare nulla ac, tincidunt tellus. Nam tortor lorem, aliquet ut
                    efficitur vel,
                </p>
                <p>
                    ullamcorper vel metus. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur
                    ridiculus mus.
                    Nam v
                    itae odio arcu. Phasellus fermentum nisi ipsum, a viverra urna placerat dignissim. Ut tempus finibus
                    mauris
                    faucibus consequat. Proin eu risus interdum, malesuada lectus id, egestas tortor. In imperdiet eget
                    augue et semper.
                    Sed risus justo, pulvinar id velit et, ullamcorper posuere ex. Nulla vel laoreet purus. Vivamus sed
                    venenatis erat,
                    in aliquam lectus. Mauris et lectus id eros feugiat viverra eu eu massa.
                </p>
                <p>
                    Nam egestas malesuada ligula quis cursus. Duis quis lorem in nunc maximus malesuada. Cras ante enim,
                    tincidunt ac
                    risus vel, elementum tincidunt erat. Ut auctor dolor a metus ornare auctor. Pellentesque at tellus
                    mi. Morbi e
                    fficitur metus vel enim ullamcorper, quis sagittis eros condimentum. Phasellus laoreet consectetur
                    lectus et dapibus.
                    Morbi tincidunt id mi nec ullamcorper. Integer dictum, justo vitae ullamcorper tristique, lorem nunc
                    rutrum augue, ut
                    pellentesque diam purus at ex. Proin sollicitudin iaculis eros.
                </p>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="full noPrint">
        <div class="mapping">
            <h3 class="mappingHeader">Screenshots</h3>
            <div class="notes">
                <div>
                    <img src="img/customRadialMenu.png" alt="Custom Menu Screenshot">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="full noPrint">
        <div id="videoWrapper">
            <div class="video-container">
                <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/4lcm4bdtkZs" frameborder="0"
                        allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the CSS

```
/*noinspection CssUnknownTarget*/
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
    background-color: #00335B;
    color: #F9F3F4;
}

img {
    max-width: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    padding: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-auto-flow: dense;
}

@media print {
    .noPrint {
        display: none !important;
    }

    @page {
        size: landscape;   /* auto is the initial value */
        /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
        margin: 25px 25px 25px 25px;
    }

    div.pageBreakAfter {
        page-break-after: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }

    div.pageBreakBefore {
        page-break-before: always;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 460px) {
    .wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .device {
        grid-column: 1 / 3;
    }

    .full {
        grid-column: auto / span 2;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 660px) {
    .wrapper {
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    }

    .device {
        grid-column: 2 / 4;
        grid-row: 1 / 3;
    }

    .wide {
        grid-column: auto / span 2;
    }

    .full {
        grid-column: auto / span 4;
    }
}

.wrapper li {
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 10px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #F9F3F4;
    text-shadow: 0 0 300px #000;
    font-size: 150%;
    text-align: center;
}

.mapping {
    border: solid #F9F3F4 3px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #F9F3F4;
    margin: 20px;
}

.mappingModeShift1 {
    border: solid #FF8C00 3px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #FF8C00;
    margin: 20px;
}

.mappingGyroShift1 {
    border: solid #00FFFF 3px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: #00FFFF;
    margin: 20px;
}

.mappingHeader {
    padding-left: 3px;
    padding-right: 3px;
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    font-style: normal;
    position: relative;
    left: 30px;
    top: -10px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    display: inline;
}

#steamDeviceContainer {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

#videoWrapper {
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
}

.video-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.video-container iframe, .video-container object, .video-container embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.actionBind {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.notes {
    margin-left: 30px;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.boundTo {
    font-size: xx-small;
    vertical-align: super;
    padding: 2px;
}

.modeShift1 {
    color: #FF8C00 !important;
}

.gyroShift1 {
    color: #00FFFF !important;
}

.yBtn {
    color: #F4D00F;
}

.xBtn {
    color: #0084C4;
}

.aBtn {
    color: #34A853;
}

.bBtn {
    color: #fc0602;
}
```

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58879352/6266107

Answer (score 16, accepted):

As you have found page pages do not work inside of grid layout block.  I tried everything I could think of, but just doesn't work.

The solution to my report was to do the `page-break-before` outside the grid layout block.

It makes it a little trick, but it can be done.  You just have to make sure your `page-break` is outside any `display: grid` class.

Comment: It also doesn't seem to work with CSS **flex** either....