# Why doesn't page-break work with CSS display grid?

Tags: html, css, css-grid, page-break

I'm making an HTML document using CSS grid layout, and then I want to print it.

The problem is that when I print the document some elements overflow to the next. So I added `page-break-inside` to my grid elements, but it doesn't change anything. Elements from one page still overflow to the other. `page-break-inside` works perfectly when there is **no** `display:grid`, but **with** `display:grid` it doesn't. Here are two samples [with grid](https://jsfiddle.net/stanimirsp5/nLqdhf4y/1/) and [without grid](https://jsfiddle.net/stanimirsp5/d4g2fnvw/3/).

So:

1. Does `page-break` work with `display:grid`, because in my situation it doesn't ?
2. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: Just adding this as a comment rather than an answer because I'm not 100% on this, but afaik it won't work inside either grid or flex layout items. I _assume_ this is due to the way those two APIs work, the fact that the size of the elements within them is elastic and calculated on the fly, and complex print support does not seem built in. You can break after a grid/flex element, but  (as far as I know) not inside it: one or more controlled grid layouts per page, not controlled grid layouts across pages

Comment: @DanCouper FYI I rejected your edit because it was an attempt to reply; if you think OP meant different properties, you should ask them that via the comments and have them confirm it rather than assume. One of the reasons for this is that, if you're right, sometimes your edit suggestion is better off as an answer.

Comment: @TylerH it's not an attempt to reply, the question is regarding `page-break-inside`, there isn't a CSS property called `page-break`. I don't _think_ the OP meant something different, he _did_ mean something different and provided an example supporting that, the question makes absolutely no sense otherwise.

Comment: @TylerH: DanCouper's edits match the question to the fiddles, so it's safe to assume the author tried to abbreviate the property by just calling it "page-break" when they really ought to just spell it out in full.

Comment: Actually by ‘page-break’ I meant all three types (before, after and inside), but thanks for clarifying the question.

Comment: @DanCouper See OP's comment as a case in point. Even if you think you're right on that, it's best to confirm.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. Breaking in grid layout as defined in [css-break-3§3.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3/#break-between) and [css-grid-1§12](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/#pagination) isn't supported by any browser yet. Also, there isn't any specification for `[page-]break-inside` in grid layouts, only `[page-]break-before` and `[page-]break-after`.
2. I suspect you'll need to manually break your grid layout into separate grids with dummy break elements in the right spots.