# CSS Paged Media: Cannot achieve desired breaking behaviour (break-after, break-before doing nothing)

Tags: css

Here's the layout of the relative part of my document:

```html
<!-- ↑ more sections -->
<section>
  <h2>Header 2</h2>
  <div class="subsection">
    <div><h3>Header 3</h3></div>
    <div>
      <h4>Header 4</h4>
      <div class="body-text"><!-- Parsed markdown text --></div>
      <h4>Header 4</h4>
      <div class="body-text"><!-- Parsed markdown text --></div>
      <!-- ↓ And so on... -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subsection">
    <div><h3>Header 3</h3></div>
    <div>
      <h4>Header 4</h4>
      <div class="body-text"><!-- Parsed markdown text --></div>
      <!-- ↓ And so on... -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="subsection">
    <div><h3>Header 3</h3></div>
    <div>
      <h4>Header 4</h4>
      <div class="body-text"><!-- Parsed markdown text --></div>
      <!-- ↓ And so on... -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ↓ and so on... -->
</section>
<!-- ↓ more secitons -->
```

Which looks like:
[image]

And as for where I'd like page-breaks to be able to happen:

- You ***cannot*** break between an `h2` and the first `.subsection`;
- You ***cannot*** break between an `h4` and its `.body-text`;
- You ***can*** break between a `.body-text` and the `h4` following it;
- You ***can*** break within a `.body-text` if it gets too long;
- You ***can*** break between a `.subsection` and another `.subsection`

---

Here's what I've tried so far:

```css
/* Borders to show where I do and do not want breaks in the following screenshot */
h2 {
  break-before: auto;   /* ✅ */
  break-after: avoid;   /* ❌ */
  border-top: 1px solid forestgreen !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
}

.subsection:first-of-type {
  break-before: avoid;  /* ❌ */
  break-after: auto;    /* ✅ */
  border-top: 1px solid red !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid forestgreen !important;
}

h4 {
  break-before: auto;  /* ✅ */
  break-after: avoid;  /* ❌ */
  border-top: 1px solid forestgreen !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red !important;
}

.subsection:first-of-type h4 {
  break-before: avoid;  /* ❌ */
  border-top: 1px solid red !important;
}

.body-text {
  break-before: avoid;  /* ❌ */
  break-after: auto;    /* ✅ */
  border-top: 1px solid red !important;
  border-bottom: 1px solid forestgreen !important;
}
```

This seems to be fairly synonomous with what I've outlined above. However, I see
the following once I go to print:
[image]

You can see that, even though I've been explicit with `break-*: auto;`, there is
still a break between the *Course Content Creator* `h4` and its following
`.body-text`. **What is stopping it from breaking at the green line immediately
preceeding it (after the *Web Application Development* line)?** Surely these two
boxes should be glued together.

The only thing that seems to actually do… *anything* is using
`break-inside: avoid;` on the `sections`:

```css
section {
  break-inside: avoid;
  background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
/* ↓ CSS from above... ↓ */
```

[image]

Clearly, this is not the correct way to go about things, since I very much do
not want to avoid breaks inside of `section`s. It's just that this is the only
thing that seem to affect how the document is actually printed.

---

I'm doing this in Chrome, version 83.0.4103.106. Firefox 77.0.1 performs the
same way.

If it makes a difference, The `.subsections` are actually Vue components, which
are slotted into each `section`'s component. I don't see how this would be the
problem, though, since I've double-checked with Chrome DevTools that even
through all the CSS scoping that happens, every CSS property is applied to the
correct element. In any case, the source code for this project is fully visible
here: [github.com/matthew-e-brown/resume](https://github.com/matthew-e-brown/resume).

Comment: Just curious if you have read through the [CSS-Tricks article about break-inside](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/)? Since this class is not fully supported in all cases they use a syntax like this that may help you:
`-webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;`
`page-break-inside: avoid;`
`break-inside: avoid`

Comment: @crazymatt Thanks for the pointer. Since this is a Vue app, the prefixed properties have been being automatically generated at some part of the Webpack process anyways: unfortunately, adding them made no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After giving up for just about two years and only just now deciding to look into this again, I've found my answer. The problem comes from the fact that my document uses CSS Grid to lay content out side-by-side. As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58880333/10549827), the [W3 specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-break-3) for this sort of behaviour is still in the candidate stage.

So, it looks like I was just a little bit ahead of the curve. At the very least, there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the CSS code itself

Answer (score 0):

`break-inside: avoid` on a `section` does not imply a `section` can never have a page-break. It implies that it should be avoided if possible.

It also looks like you do want to allow pagebreaks inside the `.subsection` divs, opposed to inside the `section`. `page-break: avoid` on the `.subsections` is what caused them to go to the next page when they don't fit.

```
/*prevent page breaking inside section, when a section doesn't fit it will display on the next page */
section {
  break-inside: avoid;
}
/*try not to break between h2 and section*/
h2 + .subsection {
  break-before: avoid;
}
```

**How to think about page-breaks**

I think it may be useful to describe how I think about the main page break options. It may help your understanding.

`page-break: inside`: glues together all the content inside this element. It will try to act as a single block.

`break-before: avoid`: glues the element before it to the current element so they try to act as a single block.

`break-after: avoid`: glues the element after it to the current element so they try to act as a single block.

Comment: Hi @RMo. I worry that my question was a bit too wishy-washy (This document is my resume and, for some reason, past-me was apprehensive about posting screenshots of it, even though it's public). I've rewritten my question to be a little more clear as to what I'm trying to do (including showing more of what the content actually looks like), since it got a little confusing/messy with my previous edits. Unfortunately, the code you've supplied is very similar to some of the things I'd tried already; it did not work. Would you mind taking another look, now that I've rewritten my question? Thanks. :)

Comment: @matthew-e-brown You can also glue together `h4` and following `.body-text` using something like `h4+.body-text{break-before:avoid}`. If you don't glue elements together or use `break-inside: avoid` on one of the parent elements the page-break behaviour will be to break as normal when appropriate.

Comment: I already do have `break-before: avoid;` set on the `.body-text` (using `h4 + ...` would be pointless, since all `.body-text` are immediately after an `h4` anyways), as well as `break-after: avoid;` on the `h4`s immediately before them, for the sake of being explicit. Setting `break-inside: avoid;` causes the page-break to happen way up at the top of the section, before the *Working Experience* header, even though large chunk of the *Working Experience* section could have fit on the page. You can see what I mean in the final screenshot of my question. TL;DR: I have already tried this 

Comment: Hmm looks like browsers are not properly supporting `break-after: avoid`.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of, haha.

Comment: You could wrap parts that shouldn't break in divs with `break-inside: avoid`. That works. But that does not seem like an elegant solution to me.