# CSS Grid split to multiple pages when printing

Tags: css, media-queries, css-grid, fluid-layout, css-print

I organize img elements into grid using grid layout. The issue is during printing, the grid cells, that are on the page split get divided. It is not really surprising, but I would like them not to. I would like to find a way to tell the grid to align the cell divider with the page.

Any ideas?

I am using a workaround that simply `media query` replace `grid` with simple old `inline-blocks`. But I very much like the fact that grid can fluidly scale the cells in range of widths via `grid-column-template: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(250px, 1fr))`. So any solution that satisfies this auto scaling and printing without JS works for me.

[image]

Comment: Half-way there... `page-break-inside: avoid` on grid element does the trick but forces the element to have a break before itself, which can leave a lot of blank space on previous page. Trying to get rid of that now.

Comment: There's an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/58879352/6266107